# Unity: get height of GameObject with content size fitter attached

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, height

I have a GameObject with a Content Size Fitter attached and would like to read out the height of the GameObject. Based on reading a dozen or so forums posts i've tried a lot of things, but can't get it to work. I think that this code should be *almost* correct, yet, it doesn't give me the right number:

```
GameObject go;    // The game object whose height i want to read out
...
// Force rebuild before reading out height
LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(go.GetComponent<RectTransform>());
// Read out height
float h = go.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height;
```

Unfortunately, this does not give me the correct height, in the sense that it does not correspond to what i see in the inspector. The code returns a height of around 2400, while the inspector says that it is 1257.8 (which corresponds to what i see on the screen) - see screenshot below. Any help would be appreciated!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb9Wb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [RectTransform.sizeDelta](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-sizeDelta.html). I've used it to set the height of RectTransforms in a few projects. Presumably you could just use it to get the height too.

Answer (score 0):

I have only been able to do this using Text.preferredWidth and preferredHeight, these seem to update immediately on changing the text. Of course, this only works if you are fitting to a Text.